# Bluetooth driver not found

Tags: bluetooth

May you give a link to activate bluetooth in ubuntu 14.04? I have tried a few google search but failed.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the terminal results of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; lsmod | grep bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; uname -a`

Comment: Can you add the info from the command to your post?